# Imagemap Rollover and Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

```
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus" />
</map>
```

I need to 1) change opacity on mouseover to highlight the hovered area and 2) add simple tooltip to show details of the hovered area.

Is it possible? Is there any jquery plugin that would let me do both.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.frankmanno.com/ideas/css-imagemap/

http://frankmanno.com/ideas/css-imagemap-redux/