# Display formatted text in HTML title attribute over imagemap

Tags: html, imagemap

I have code for an imagemap which has a few links. The code currently looks like this:

```
<img title = "Concept" border = "0" src = "${concept.png}" usemap = "#myAppMap">

<map name = "myAppMap">

   <area shape = "polygon" coords = "..." title = "title text" />
   <area shape = "polygon" coords = "..." title = "title text" />
   <area shape = "polygon" coords = "..." title = "title text" />
</map>
```

Where if a user runs a mouse over the area of each shape, the cursor becomes a 'hand' and the title text is displayed. But is it possible to format the title text at all so that I can use line breaks and maybe even lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to remove the title text and add a mouseover event method that display's a block element on the mouse current's position. In this element you can add whatever you want. This is called a "tooltip" of which there are several to be found on the internet, like [jQuery tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html)

Comment: I think it cannot be done. The text that is being displayed when you hover your image now, is the browser's implementation of the title attribute that you specified. It's basic HTML which you cannot extend with a HTML value or whatsoever.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks.

Comment: No problem...maybe some other genious has a solution for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Almost identical question asked a year ago, it can be done with CSS:

[Imagemap Rollover and Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890882/imagemap-rollover-and-tooltip)

Here's the example, you can have multiple lines by nature of controlling the size of the container that shows on hover:

http://frankmanno.com/ideas/css-imagemap-redux/

If you want to get a bit more fancy and are using jQuery:

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster

Answer (score 0):

If you're using some server technology (e.g. PHP) you can create line breaks in the title text by adding a newline char to the string being displayed. (I'm using PHP_EOL, but you could use "\r\n" too.)

```
<a href="#" title="<?php echo 'Line 1'.PHP_EOL.'Line 2'; ?>">Link</a>
```

Of course, the same result can be achieved by adding a html entity:

```
<a href="#" title="Line 1&#10;Line2">Link</a>
```

I'm not sure if this works in all browsers, but it works in the most recent versions of Chrome, Firefox and Opera (Jan 2013).